# CVE-2021-45105 wso2 vulnerability

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there any fix for the CVE-2021-45105 log4j vulnerability for wso2 products?

Apache Log4j Denial of Service (DOS) Vulnerability (Log4Shell)

The one they shared in below link is for a different CVE.
https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=180948677

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, you can implement one of the mitigation techniques described here: [Apache Log4j Security Vulnerabilities](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html#CVE-2021-45105)

Comment: Is there any script or steps which advise on how to do the mitigation suggested by Apache below:  

#############

Alternatively, this infinite recursion issue can be mitigated in configuration:

In PatternLayout in the logging configuration, replace Context Lookups like ${ctx:loginId} or $${ctx:loginId} with Thread Context Map patterns (%X, %mdc, or %MDC).
Otherwise, in the configuration, remove references to Context Lookups like ${ctx:loginId} or $${ctx:loginId} where they originate from sources external to the application such as HTTP headers or user input.

#############

Comment: Well, they write exactly what to do. Check your log4 config file - log4j.properties. Find `.layout.pattern` config, and replace/remove any context lookups - if you use them. In wso2 product you have one config file for log4j.properties / log4j2.properties